# quake linking to libpng

Tags: qt, qmake, libpng

I am using qt and qmake to generate the makefile for my C++ project and I recently pulled in a sub-project from another group which uses libpng functionality in their code. When I tried to compile it, it gave undefined reference for PNG functions like:

```
undefined reference to symbol png_set_sig_bytes
```

So, I was guessing that I need to link to `limping`. What I did was added something like:

```
LIBS += png
```

Also tried

```
LIBS += libpng
```

Both of these commands ended up with `No such file for directory error`.

Can someone point out how I can link to the png library from a make pro file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out, I needed to do:

```
LIBS += -lpng
```

This is assuming that the library can be found in the path where the compiler looks. Else, the path needs to be added with a `-L` flag as well.